# "Identifier expected" how to solve and what does it mean to keep it inside the method

Tags: java

I get this error:

```
<identifier> expected : stayer.stretchPeriodicity();
                                                 ^
```

And I see people telling that this needs to be inside a method but it's already a method ? and I just want to call it ?

what do I do then ?

Here is my code

```
class Runner {
    double pace;

    public Runner(double averagePace) {
        pace = averagePace;
    }

    public void workout(double distanceKm) {
        System.out.println(distanceKm + " километра позади");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner stayer = new Runner(4.47);
        stayer.start();
        stayer.workout(14.3);
        /* Под этим комментарием вызываете метод stretchPeriodicity */
        stayer.stretchPeriodicity();
    }
}

// класс Athlete
class Runner extends Athlete {

    public void stretchPeriodicity() {
        System.out.println("Рекомендуемая периодичность растяжки: после каждой тренировки");
    }
}
```

Comment: The first `Runner` class should be the `Athlete` class!

Comment: Your `main` method needs to be inside of the class definition.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two Runner classes?
You can merge them together or rename the upper class and need to correct the closing braces, main method has been orphan.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has problems:

1. You can't have two classes with the same name. to solve: change your second class name.
2. Your main method must be in a class. to solve: put your main method into the first class.
3. You can have one class for the main method and one class for Runner class like this:

---

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runner stayer = new Runner(4.47);

    stayer.start();

    stayer.workout(14.3);
    /* Под этим комментарием вызываете метод stretchPeriodicity */
    stayer.stretchPeriodicity();

}
```

}

```
class Runner extends Athlete {
double pace;

public Runner(double averagePace) {

    pace = averagePace;

}

public void workout(double distanceKm) {

    System.out.println(distanceKm + " километра позади");

}

public void stretchPeriodicity()

{

    System.out.println("Рекомендуемая периодичность растяжки: после каждой тренировки");

}
```

}

---

Remember your file name should be the same with the first class name. here your file name should be "MainClass".

Good luck.